# Safeguard against system-hang due to high memory usage

Tags: linux, memory, process, architecture, operating-system

On my computer, which has Ubuntu installed on it, I can freeze the entire GUI by running a simple program that uses a lot of memory. After that, I can't even use the GUI to stop or pause the problematic program.

How can I configure my OS so that this problem does not happen?

Is there a similar problem in Android, Windows 10, Mac or iOS?

Here is the C++ program.

```cxx
#define L 256*1024*1024
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *c=new char[L];
        for(long i=0;i<L;i++)
            c[i]='a';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: This program causes problem in Windows 8.1 also. Even Alt-Ctrl-Del doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide more details of the simple program?  If it's that simple, you can post the code?

Comment: @MartinJames Please see the edit.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/398236/oom-killer-not-working

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks, but actually I wanted a passive mechanism rather than an active 'killer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe process limits (controlled by `ulimit` command in bash) is what you are looking for.  You can set the maximum amount of Virtual Memory your process can allocate with `ulimit -v`, the argument being size in KB.  For example, running:

```
ulimit -v 100000
```

*before* running your program should kill it before it can exhaust the memory in the system ([see Ubuntu page for more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120765/memory-limiting-solutions-for-greedy-applications-that-can-crash-os)).  Note that limits are *inherited* i.e. your ulimit command is setting the limit for your shell, which is then inherited by *all* the child processes started by it.